# d3 reading data list syntax

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to make a line graph using some data formatted like this:

```
{state: 'New York', value:{year_2000: 1000, year_2001: 20000}
```

how do you reference the year in this data?

```
var year = [2000, 2001];

var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(year)
    .rangeRoundPoints([0, 100]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
       return d.value;
    })])
    .range([0, 100]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tick(0);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("left")
    .tick(10);

var valueLine = d3.svg.line()
    .xScale(function(d) { return xScale(year); })
    .yScale(function(d) { return yScale(d.value); })
```

I think the `valueline` setup is wrong. I would like to know how to reference the year and the according values to complete the line chart. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put: you can't use that data structure.

In D3, the line generator `d3.line()` in v4 or `d3.svg.line()` in v3...

> Generates a line for the given **array** of data. (emphasis mine)

Therefore, you have to change your data structure, for one in which **each data point** is an element (such as an object) inside the array.

For instance, like this:

```js
var data = {
  state: 'New York',
  value: {
    year_2000: 1000,
    year_2001: 20000
  }
};

var newValue = [];
for(var key in data.value){
 newValue.push({year: key.split("_")[1], value: data.value[key]})
};

data.value = newValue;

console.log(data)
```

Then, you can use it to generate the line.

One additional problem: your line generator is incorrect, the methods are named `x` and `y`.

Here is the demo with those changes:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg")

var data = {
  state: 'New York',
  value: {
    year_2000: 1000,
    year_2001: 20000
  }
};

var newValue = [];
for (var key in data.value) {
  newValue.push({
    year: key.split("_")[1],
    value: data.value[key]
  })
};

data.value = newValue;

var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(data.value.map(function(d) {
    return d.year
  }))
  .rangeRoundPoints([80, 280]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data.value, function(d) {
    return d.value;
  })])
  .range([120, 10]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(xScale)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(yScale)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(5);

var valueLine = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return xScale(d.year);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return yScale(d.value);
  });

svg.append("path")
  .datum(data.value)
  .attr("d", valueLine)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "teal")
  .attr("stroke-width", 2);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,120)")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(80,0)")
  .call(yAxis);
```

```css
.axis line,
.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I'm created a new array to split and store the data like what you have here as "newValue". Is there a way to check what's stored in that array? I used console.log(newValue[0]) but it returned undefined.

Comment: Share your exact code somewhere (like JSfiddle) and I'll have a look.

Comment: after i push the data into the new array, it shows empty array. is it because my original data is in an array? it's stored as [{ }, {}]

Comment: Your data is now an **array**. You have to change several things, starting with the `forEach`. Have a look: https://jsfiddle.net/63d5spv0/7/